# CORS issue: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: cors, axios

In my project, I want to request data via a third party API. And came across a CORS issue as following:

In my front end code, I use `axios` to send the ajax get request with the most basic usage as following:

```
  getPositions () {
    return axios.get('http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/vehicles/')
  }
```

and as the title shows, the Browser block the request with the following error message :

`Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

I known something about CORS, and known what the preflight is. But still confused with the issue.

I check the issue in the devtools of the browser. And found that the `request headers` part goes as following:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
```

The header of `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization` was listed there. I think that's the reason for this issue. But the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` is used to let the server know which HTTP headers will be used when the actual request is made [Access-Control-Request-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers)
.

But I don't plan to send `Authorization` header, as I shown in my code I didn't set any headers at all. So why the browser block the request?

Comment: Do you have cors enabled on your server? I would recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors to ensure your preflight options get handled correctly.

Comment: It's a third party API, out of my control. I can do nothing about server side

Comment: Do you have axios.defaults.headers.common or something set? Regardless, if you make the same request with XHR or the Fetch API and the Authorization header doesn’t get added in those cases, then it sounds like you need to look into your axis setup. On the other hand, if the Authorization header gets added even when you make the same request with XHR or the Fetch API, then maybe you have an extension or something that’s adding it. In which case I guess you’d want to disable your extensions.